# Find scores when weighted average is known.

Tags: statistics

I know the weighted average A (300) of two numbers RA and LA. The weights are .8 and .2 respectively. .8RA +.2LA=300. How do I calculate RA and LA?

Comment: How is this question off topic.  It is the same as many other questions here as I discovered when searching for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t in general unless more information is known. For example, $RA=LA=300$ satisfies the equation but so does $RA=100, LA=1100$. In fact, there are infinitely many different solutions ($RA, LA$ pairs satisfying your known constraints) to the equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was the conclusion I was coming to based on my ancient algebra memories. 2 unknown variables need 2 equations to solve for. The presentation of the idea left out what the other equation concept was so I will have sort through the data more to see if I can glean a clue.  Again thank you.